# Limit of a function proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, proof-verification

[image: question]

My proof:

By Bernoulli Equation $(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}=b(1+(na)/b)^{1/n}$

By definition of a limit, fix $\epsilon > 0$ and $N>(b\epsilon^n)/a$

Then, $|a_n - b | = |(na/b)^{1/n}|<(Na/b)^{1/n}<\epsilon$

This is different to the solution I have been given. Is this still correct?

Comment: $(a^{n}+b^{n})^{1/n}\neq b(1+(na)/b)^{1/n}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

As you are told, it is convenient to write $$a^n+b^n=b^n \Big(1+(\frac{a}{b})^n\Big)$$ So, raising both sides to power $\frac{1}{n}$ gives $$\left(a^n+b^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=b(1+r^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ with $r=\frac{a}{b}$. When $n$ becomes very large $r^n$ becomes smaller and smaller and so $1+r^n$ goes to $1$ as well as the power.